# Laravel 5.4 Session is not retaining

Tags: php, session, laravel-5.4

Im newbie to laravel, So i got this problem with the session. Im actually fetching a xml response and converting it to an array and storing it to session:

Here is my controller that is accepting the request, convert the response to array and storing it on session.

```
public function HotelSearch(Request $request){
        $rezlive = new RezLiveSearch();
        $rezliveSearch = $rezlive->hotelSearchByCountry($request);
        $request->session()->put('hotelSearchResult', $rezliveSearch);
        $theResult = $request->session()->get('hotelSearchResult');
        return view('search-result',compact('theResult'));
    }
```

So it was storing and i can view the search result on my view page. But when i navigate to other pages that session which i just stored is not carried over. I tried to store a normal string and its working fine i can access it all over the application. Any one can help me with this please ?

BTW i'm using laravel 5.4

Comment: Have you tried to serialize and deserialize your data?

Comment: can you dump the result? is it a resource or plain array ?

Comment: @MateuszSip I will Try to do that.

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix its resource since i just converted a xml response. I cant dump it here since it got sensitive data.

Comment: you can't pass a resource to an session, it should an array or plain object

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix  Thanks for that, i ended up storing the xml response into session and then retrieving it and convert it to array when ever i want to access something out of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$rezlive = new RezLiveSearch();
        $rezliveSearch = $rezlive->hotelSearchByCountry($request);
        $request->session()->put('hotelSearchResult', $rezliveSearch);`

An resource can't be stored in session.

from php manual

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php

> A resource is a special variable, holding a reference to an external resource.

You need to fetch the XML data from the resource and store it to session, alternatively you can store into cache the XML , associate it with an random generated ID and avoid placing too much information in session.